# Appending number to QString with arg() , is there better ways?

Tags: qt, qstring, qt4.7

I've been using QString::number () to convert numbers to string for long time , now i'm wondering if there's something better than following:

```
  int i = 0;
  QString msg = QString ("Loading %1").arg (QString::number (i));
```

How can i spare QString::number () ? i checked document , seems only "%1" is applicable , no other stuff like "%d" could work

Comment: What is the motivation? To save typing or something else?

Comment: @r_ahlskog , yeah , sort of , and i'm thinking if `printf` like format string is possible

Comment: @r_ahlskog , %1 seems pretty general

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can directly use `arg()` like this

```
int i = 0;
QString msg = QString ("Loading %1").arg(i);
```

Qt will automatically convert it for you

Answer (score 14):

QString's `arg()` function does indeed implement many different types and automatically detect what you provide it. Providing multiple parameters to a single `arg()` call like so

```
// Outputs "one two three"
QString s = QString("%1 %2 %3").arg("one", "two", "three")
```

is only implemented for QString (and hence `const char*`) parameters.

However, you can chain arg calls together and still use the numbering system:

```
int i = 5;
size_t ui = 6;
int j = 12;
// Outputs "i: 5, ui: 6, j: 12"
qDebug() << QString("i: %1, ui: %2, j: %3").arg(i).arg(ui).arg(j);
// Also outputs "i: 5, ui: 6, j: 12"
qDebug() << QString("i: %1, ui: %3, j: %2").arg(i).arg(j).arg(ui);
```

### UPDATE

Qt 5.14 introduced [a variadic templated form of arg](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg-22) which should allow multiple non-string args to a single call:

```cpp
template <typename Args> QString QString::arg(Args &&... args) const
```

> Args can consist of anything that implicitly converts to QString, QStringView or QLatin1String.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at QString documentation. You have plenty of ::arg method overloads, that take different types. QString doesn't need to know what type will be under %n, method replacing that %n will know it and put proper value.