# Copy text and placeholders, variables to the clipboard

Tags: c++, qt, clipboard

In my application I want generate random numbers or strings with a text in front of it. It is important for me that the text won't appear in my window, but instead gets copied to the clipboard.

```
int randomnumber = rand() % 46 + 1;

QClipboard *cb = QApplication::clipboard();
cb->setText("Just a test text. And here we have a placeholder! %i", randomnumber);
```

QClipboard works fine with plain text (in this example "Just a test text. And here we have a placeholder!"). But I also want to copy placeholders for random numbers so that the copied text looks like this:

Just a test text. And here we have a placeholder! 42

Sadly I get the error message:
invalid conversion from 'int' to 'QClipboard::Mode'

Is it possible to copy text, placeholders and so on to the clipboard and not just plain text?

Comment: setText is not like printf. You need QString::arg() here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not using the function `setText` correctly. The canonical prototype is `text(QString & subtype, Mode mode = Clipboard) const` from the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qclipboard.html).

What you want to do is assemble your `QString` ahead of time and then use that to populate the clipboard.

```
QString message = QString("Just a test text. 
     And here we have a placeholder! %1").arg(randomnumber);
cb->setText(message);
```

Note that the argument is `%1` instead of `%f`. The argument numbers are sequential in `Qt`. Please check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255639/appending-number-to-qstring-with-arg-is-there-better-ways) article for more information.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You must format your string before passing it as parameter to `cb->setText`.

just do this:

> QString txt = QString("Just a test text. And here we have a placeholder! %1").arg(randomnumber);

And then:

> cb->setText(txt);